# Adding result set into ArrayList take so much of time

Tags: java, arraylist, resultset, jdbc-odbc

Here is my code where i am running my query and adding result set into ArrayList .
Modified code

```
private ArrayList<String> getEventsFromShares() throws SQLException {
    Statement eventStmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ArrayList<String> eventsList = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    try {
        eventStmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Getting data from shares table");
        rs = eventStmt.executeQuery(
                "select s.event_id from tso_shares s join ife.entityids i on s.event_id = i.entityid where to_char(i.datemodified,'YYYY') = "
                        + year + "");
        eventStmt.setFetchSize(500);
        while (rs.next()) {
            eventsList.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        rs.close();
        eventStmt.close();
    }
    System.out.println("eventsMap" + eventsList.size());
    return eventsList;
}
```

query comes out in few seconds only but addog into ArrayList takes almost 15 minutes of time .

Can some one help me identify the issue or how can i improve my code .

Comment: How big is your data? Also, is it really adding the Strings to your ArrayList or getting the Strings out of the ResultSet?

Comment: Print some timestamps before the execution of the query, after it and after the `while` loop.

Comment: @jalako total size is 70k only second part i have to confirm

Comment: I wonder if making your result set scrollable has a performance cost? Why not use [`TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY)? In which case you’d be using defaults only and could omit both arguments.

Comment: @BasilBourque i modified that but still same slowness

Comment: @Shailendra Define “slowness”, give specific numbers. Explain your hardware, OS, database, and JDBC driver.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you only want column `event_id` from table `s` so change your SQL statement to `select s.event_id` instead of `select s.*`. Then you can extract the value from the `ResultSet` using `rs.getString(1)` rather than `rs.getString("event_id")`

Also you can give your `ArrayList` an initial capacity if you know approximately how many rows your SQL query will return, e.g.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(500)
```

Comment: Its not improving for me even after all the changes

Comment: Then I think you need to profile it and see what amount of time each part of your code is taking. Perhaps setting the fetch size to 500 is your problem? I'm only guessing. Profile your code first. I don't know if it will make a difference, but have you tried using `java.sql.PreparedStatement` instead of `java.sql.Statement`?

Comment: @Abra I suggest you put those suggestions from your Comment into your Answer.